# When plotting a dataframe, how to set the x-range for a 'YYYY-MM' value

Tags: pandas, plot

I have a pandas df with the below values. I can create a nifty chart that looks like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = pdf_month.plot(x="month", y="count", kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to truncate the date range (to ignore 1900-01-01 and other months that not import, but everytime I try I get error messages (see below). The date range would be something like '2016-01' to '2018-04'
`ax.set_xlim(pdf_month['month'][17],pdf_date['count'].values.max())`

where `pdf_month['month'][17]` gives you a value of `u'2017-01'`.

```
pdf_month.printSchema
root
 |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

How do I set the range on the month values for a x-value that isn't really an int or a date. I still have the original, pre-grouped dates. Is there a better way to group by month that would allow you to customize the x-axis?

error messages:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

sample output of pd_month

```
     month  count
0   1900-01 353
1   2015-09 1
2   2015-10 2
3   2015-11 2
4   2015-12 1
5   2016-01 1
6   2016-02 1
7   2016-03 3
8   2016-04 2
9   2016-05 5
10  2016-06 7
11  2016-07 13
12  2016-08 12
13  2016-09 41
14  2016-10 19
15  2016-11 17
16  2016-12 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Series date indexing, Pandas Series allow for date slicing as follows:

```
df.month['2016-01': '2018-04']
```

This works with datetime indexes.